# Extracting Variables from Text Files

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to write a sed script to search a text file for the words "SETTLEMENT DATE" and then capture the date that appears after the word instance and then rename the test file to the settlement date.

Text File

```
This is a sample line in a text file -- SETTLEMENT DATE June 1, 2020
```

```
sed -ne 's/^*SETTLEMENT DATE/ p'
```

Comment: I sort have got it working using: sed -n 's/.* SETTLEMENT DATE\(.*\)/\1 /p' test.dat

Answer (score 0):

You're very close. You just appear to be missing a `/` to replace `SETTLEMENT DATE` with an empty string before printing the pattern space.

```
sed -ne 's/SETTLEMENT DATE //p' tmp.txt
```

Here, `p` is not a separate `sed` function (which would print the current pattern space), but a flag on the `s` function which prints the pattern space *if* a replacement was made.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep 'SETTLEMENT DATE' filename | sed 's/.*SETTLEMENT DATE//g' | xargs -n1 -I {} mv filename '{}'
```

Above comnand will find line with text 'SETTLEMENT DATE'  from 'file' and then extract date and rename same file as date

Answer (score 0):

This one-liner Perl script will search a given text file (e.g. test.dat) for the words "SETTLEMENT DATE" and then captures the date, formats it by removing spaces and replacing comma with hyphen, and outputs the proper rename (mv) command for execution.

```
perl -lne 'BEGIN {$file = $ARGV[0]} if (/SETTLEMENT DATE(.+)/) { $d=$1; $d =~ s/\s+//g; $d =~ s/,/\-/g; print "mv $file $d.dat"}' test.dat
```

and if it finds a string like:

```
This is a sample line in a text file -- SETTLEMENT DATE June 1, 2020
```

will produce this result (rename/mv command):

```
mv test.dat June1-2020.dat
```